# how to add file extension in url while passing it to ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, tabs, csv

i want to save/open a file in txt format other then CSV in SSRS 2005. So any one who knows how to add file extension in url that can overirde default extension in SSRS 2005..

Comment: you want to open the file as a datasource?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you want to export a report to a text file, but not CSV format? You haven't specified what other format you want, but if you want to output to a text file with a different kind of delimiter (for example Tab or | ) then you can do that by rendering the report via URL Access and overriding some of the rendering extension parameters.

For example, to export to a TAB delimited file with the extension .TXT:

http://SERVERNAME/reportserver/?%2fReportFolder%2fMyReport&rs:Format=CSV&rc:**FieldDelimiter=%09**&rc:**Extension=TXT**

As far as I can tell SSRS 2005 does not support setting these values in rsreportserver.config unfortunately. However SSRS 2008 does, which means in 2008 you can create a new rendering extension based on CSV and specify these settings. Users can then select the render format from the Export list in Report Manager, however as I mentioned 2005 does not support this so I think URL Access is your only option.

[CSV Device Info settings for SSRS 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155365(SQL.90).aspx)

[Report Server URL Access for SSRS 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586(SQL.90).aspx)